# using Altapp/Meteor-reCAPTCHA I get error as "Uncaught Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey"

Tags: node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6, recaptcha

On localhost the app works great with `Altapp/Meteor-reCAPTCHA`, but on live server the recaptcha does not appear, When I checked inside console log , i get below error

```
Uncaught Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey
    at new yq (recaptcha__en.js:360)
    at new Wq (recaptcha__en.js:367)
    at ir (recaptcha__en.js:373)
    at recaptcha__en.js:377
    at Vq (recaptcha__en.js:367)
    at recaptcha__en.js:376
    at recaptcha__en.js:387
    yq @ recaptcha__en.js:360
    Wq @ recaptcha__en.js:367
    ir @ recaptcha__en.js:373
    (anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:377
    Vq @ recaptcha__en.js:367
    (anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:376
    (anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:387
```

I have already followed exact directions for code 
 at https://github.com/Altapp/Meteor-reCAPTCHA

Comment: Did you add your public key from Google on the client-side?

Comment: I already said that on local host it works perfectly fine. So it clearly indicates I did all formalities.

Comment: @AnkurSoni Much of the time `localhost` is special-cased to make local development easier. The question is perfectly valid. You haven't shown any of the code where you initialize the library, so I'm not sure how you're expecting us to answer this.